# Get or default function in JQ?

Tags: json, jq

Assuming there is a json file:

```
{
  "columns": {
    "id": {
      "required": true,
      "type": "integer"
    },
    "name": {
      "required": false,
      "type": "string"
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to use `jq` to get the value "required" field for each column. If the field "required" does not exist, it should return the default value `false`.

Specifically:

```
jq '.columns.id | getOrDefault("required", false)'  # true
jq '.columns.name | getOrDefault("required", false)'  # false
jq '.columns.description | getOrDefault("required", false)'  # false
```

How to implement this magic getOrDefault() function in `jq`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> If the field "required" does not exist, it should return the default value false.

To implement that functionality literally, you would use `has/1` rather than `//`, e.g.:

```
   .columns.id
   | if has("required") then .required else false end
```

If the .required field is known never to be specified as `null`, then the two techniques (using `has` as above and using `// false`) are equivalent.

### getOrDefault/2

You'd almost surely never define such a function, but since you ask:

```
def getOrDefault($key; $default):
  if has($key) then .[$key] else $default end;
```

(NB: The argument separator in jq is `;`.)

### Generalized getOrDefault/2

```
# $key can be a string or a non-empty array-path
def getOrDefault($key; $default):
  if $key | type == "string"
  then if has($key) then .[$key] else $default end
  elif $key | length == 1 then getOrDefault($key[0]; $default)
  else ($key|first) as $kf
  | if has($kf) 
    then try (.[$kf] | getOrDefault($key[1:]; $default)) catch $default
    else $default
    end
  end;
```

Comment: +1 The first formula was what I needed to correctly implement `true` as the default value. In contrast, the alternative operator `(//)` would override both `null` and `false` values with the default (this would incorrectly produce a `true` value upon meeting a `false` value in the object).

Comment: +1 for this solution for the reasons @dafinguzman gave concerning `false` values (which I actually want).  However, I do NOT want a "null" string returned for `null` values, so I added a `null` value check: `if has($key) and (.[$key] != null) then .[$key] else $default end`

Comment: how might one convert these to use nested keys? The `has(nested.key)` will not work as expected.

Comment: @spagh-eddie - See new subsection: Generalized getOrDefault/2

Answer (score 48):

You can use the [alternative operator (`//`)](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://) in this particular case.

```bash
$ jq '.columns.description | .required // false' file
false
```

For a generally applicable approach, see [peak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56555442/10248678).

Comment: Note that if you want to default to an empty string, default to `empty` instead of `''` or `""`, see [github](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/354#issuecomment-43147898)