# jq get value or default if nested key not present

Tags: json, shell, null, jq

I would like to make a small `jq`-like function that does get-or-default-if-not-present similar to Python's `dict.get(key, default)`. This is the desired behavior:

```console
% echo '{"nested": {"key": "value", "tricky": null}}' > file.json

% my-jq nested.key \"default\" file.json
"value"
% my-jq nested.tricky \"default\" file.json
null
% my-jq nested.dne \"default\" file.json
"default"
```

I have tried playing with [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56555155/14062906) but it doesn't work for nested keys. Does anyone have a suggestion?

```bash
function my-jq () {                                                         
  jq --arg key "$1" --arg default "$2" \
  'if has($key) then .[$key] else $default | fromjson end' "$3"
}
```

Comment: There are a few problems. First, neither `key` nor `default` is in your environment. Second, `.[nested.key]` is not equivalent to `.nested.key`. Third, `env` doesn't contain the input that you expect `fromjson` to parse.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Your second point looks promising. How can I have both `if has(nested.key) then .nested.key` refer to the same variable? I don't think your first or third points are valid. They are defined in the function.

Comment: They are defined as ordinary shell variables, *not* environment variables.

Comment: The default value can be provided using the `//` operator. `jq --arg default foobar '.nested.dne // $default' file.json` will output `"foobar"` rather than `null`.

Comment: You are right about the environment variables. I had them set while testing and when I unset them the function fails! Will edit my post.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52178574/1126841 for a workaround. Specify a list of the keys instead of a filter, and use the `getpath` function to generate the filter.  E.g., `jq --arg default foobar --argjson key  '["nested", "key"]' 'getpath($key) // $default' file.json` outputs `"value"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your projection to make a "jq-like" function, it's fair to assume that your parameter should then be considered not just a path expression but a general jq filter, i.e. code. With the current versions of jq, there is no option or other shorthand method that works for code similar to how `--arg` and `--argjson` do for data.

You can, however, import code fragments by means of jq's [library/module system](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Modules), but with the task at hand you'd need to store the code from your function's parameter into a (temporary) file, reference it in the static part of the actual jq filter, and delete the file afterwards. This not only is cumbersome, it also needs some static overhead in the module file, which inevitably opens up Pandora's box labeled "Code injection", so you could just as well submit to the unleashed evil, and compose the actual jq filter on the fly using the literal (and potentially malicious) content of the parameter. (Note that this assumes a valid jq expression, thus using `.nested.key` etc. with a dot up front):

```bash
function my-jq() { jq "($1) // ($2)" "$3"; }
```

```bash
% my-jq .nested.key \"default\" file.json
"value"

my-jq .nested.tricky \"default\" file.json  # fails
"default"

% my-jq .nested.dne \"default\" file.json
"default"
```

This minimal approach uses the alternative operator `//`, which fails to tell an actual but falsy value ("null" or "false") apart from an empty stream (missing value). To counteract that, you could perform a check on the existence of the `path` input among the all the `paths` of the base document. This drastically reduces the kind of filters trivially accepted by your function (which with your use case in mind may even be considered a good thing, yet malicious injection is still possible), and the comparison with all paths may come with a performance penalty for base documents with complex structuring, but it meets your three test cases:

```bash
function my-jq() { jq "if any(path($1) == paths; .) then ($1) else ($2) end" "$3"; }
```

```bash
% my-jq .nested.key \"default\" file.json
"value"

my-jq .nested.tricky \"default\" file.json
null

% my-jq .nested.dne \"default\" file.json
"default"
```

Eventually, the potential performance penalty could be mitigated by combining both approaches, i.e. starting off with the faster first one for the general case, but reverting to the possibly slower second one if the first one produced an ambiguous falsy value:

```bash
function my-jq() { jq "($1) // if any(path($1) == paths; .) then ($1) else ($2) end" "$3"; }
```

```bash
% my-jq .nested.key \"default\" file.json
"value"

my-jq .nested.tricky \"default\" file.json
null

% my-jq .nested.dne \"default\" file.json
"default"
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. You are correct in assuming I only intended to handle jq-path-like inputs, not its entire suite!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a dotted path as a sequence of keys. You can turn such a path into a valid path for use with the `getpath` function, however. (There may be a cleaner, more robust way to do this.) The `//` operator provides for an alternate value should the left-hand side produce `false` or `null`.

```
$ jq  'getpath($key | ltrimstr(".") | split(".")) // $default' file.json --arg key .nested.key --arg default foobar
"value"
$ jq  'getpath($key | ltrimstr(".") | split(".")) // $default' file.json --arg key .nested.dne --arg default foobar
"foobar"
```

`$key | ltrimstr(".") | split(".")` first gets rid of the leading `.`, then splits the remaining string on the remaining `.` to produce a list of separate keys. `getpath` produces a filter using that list of keys; `getpath(["nested", "key"])` is equivalent (AFAIK) to `.nested.key`.

Comment: This is great! but I also desired `nested.tricky` to return `null`. The `//` makes it return the default.

Comment: Ah, right. Hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements go against JSON's grain a bit, but here is one possible solution, or the basis of a family of solutions.

This particular solution assumes that the path is given in array form:

```
function my-jq () {
  jq -c --argjson key "$1" --arg default "$2" '
     first(tostream | select(length == 2 and .[0] == $key)) // null
     | if . then .[1] else $default end
  ' 
}
```

Examples:

```
echo '{"nested": {"key": "value", "tricky": null}}' | my-jq2 '["nested","key"]' haha
"value"

echo '{"nested": {"key": "value", "tricky": null}}' | my-jq2 '["nested","nokey"]' haha
"haha"

echo '{"nested": {"key": "value", "tricky": null}}' | my-jq2 '["nested","tricky"]' haha
null
```

Comment: An interesting solution! Perhaps converting the "family of solutions" to a "universal solution" is possible by doing some manipulation of `select(length == 2)`. Maybe I'll play with it.